# multiple NER models in stanfordcore NLP

Tags: stanford-nlp, named-entity-recognition

I am trying to detect if a sentence has person name. I am using standford core NLP java library

```
Properties props = new Properties();
props.setProperty("annotators", "tokenize, ssplit, pos, lemma, ner, parse, dcoref");
props.setProperty("ner.model","edu/stanford/nlp/models/ner/chinese.misc.distsim.crf.ser.gz,edu/stanford/nlp/models/ner/english.all.3class.distsim.crf.ser.gz,edu/stanford/nlp/models/ner/german.conll.germeval2014.hgc_175m_600.crf.ser.gz,edu/stanford/nlp/models/ner/spanish.ancora.distsim.s512.crf.ser.gz");
standfordNERpipeline = new StanfordCoreNLP(props);
CoreDocument document = new CoreDocument(line.getText());
getStanfordPipeline.annotate(document);
CoreSentence sentence = document.sentences().get(0);
List<String> nerTags = sentence.nerTags();
```

As I wouldnt know what ethnicity the person could be, I want to use all the available NER models. I am using all the 4 NER models in prop file, separated by comma. But it seems like its always using the first model(chineese) for the classification.

How can I use all the 4 NER models on one sentence?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not really sure using foreign language `ner` models on English text is a good idea.

But if you add this to your code it will fix your issue:

`props.setProperty("ner.combinationMode", "HIGH_RECALL")`

This way all 4 models output will be allowed for all tags.

Comment: The text can be of any language.